# Smartphone <-> PC game controller options

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, smartphone

I'm trying to set up a smartphone as a gaming controller and am in process of figuring out my options.
I currently have WiFi and Bluetooth set up and working.
The WiFi app can automatically find the right PC and connect to it via UDP, the only issue is that when the network is very busy (someone is streaming a video or something), then there is some delay.

I've only tested Bluetooth with a Bluetooth 2.0 dongle and the speed is a bit too slow. Bluetooth 3.0 supposedly comes with huge speed improvements.

Are there any other options out there for me? What about WiFi direct or UWB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth 2.0 has acceptable speeds for a gaming controller. I had a bug elsewhere which caused a delay.

Answer (score 0):

*Just* a controller, or actually having multiplayer games on the device? Unity3D is a JavaScript and C# platform that can do multiplayer on almost anything.

Comment: Just a controller. Yea I'm using Unity.